# webpack 4 - simple setting, how

Tags: webpack

I have big, really big problem with webpack 4, I really can't find good tutrial how to use it, so really, really ask you about help. Theoretically it work without mistakes, but serve nothing. White page. Even if I'm not sure how to run it. Localhost:8080 ? Give nothing. Just path to page? The same. Different port? Where I find it?

I have install webpack and webpack-cli.
I have webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
            test: /\.(html)$/,
            use: ["html-loader"]
        }
      ]
    }
};
```

In package.json I have:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack --mode development --watch",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
```

I have index.js

```
var loginpage = Vue.component('login-page', require('./components/login-page/login-page.js'));


$(function() {
  var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: function(){
      return {
          name: 'main components'
      }
    },
    methods: {},
    watch: {},
    created: function(){}
  });
// end
})
```

my index.html:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Hello Vue</title>
  <meta name="" content="">

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  <div id="app" class="container">
    <login-page></login-page>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

of course login-component exist too.

Then I type npm start webpack start, no errors:

> > webpack --mode development --watch
>
> webpack is watching the files…
>
> Hash: e907caf25a8fe69c6097 Version: webpack 4.12.2 Time: 768ms Built
>   at: 2018-08-20 22:53:24   Asset      Size  Chunks             Chunk
>   Names main.js  5.29 KiB    main  [emitted]  main [./src/index.js] 327
>   bytes {main} [built]
>       + 2 hidden modules

but then I open localhost:8080 I have

> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

what I did wrong? Please, help.

Comment: ok, I found reason. In index.html container should be above script.

Comment: Post your solution as an answer